# SSIS importing Excel data via C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

I've just got started with SSIS and the processing of Excel files via C# when I stumbled over this article:

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368530/Dynamic-Excel-file-loading-with-SSIS)

The article explains how to load Excel data via SSIS into a SQL Server database.

But instead of some select statement I would need to have all the rows extracted starting from a specific row (for example row 9). Now my question is, what pieces of code do I need to change/erase in order to get me to set the starting row without the need of using any header information?

```
public SourceFileDetails ScanRows(DataSet excelDataSet, string ExtractionStatement, string FindColumn)
{
        if (excelDataSet.Tables.Count < 1)
            return (SourceFileDetails)null;

        string ExtractFields = this.ReplaceString(this.ReplaceString(ExtractionStatement, "SELECT", ""), "From [Data$]", "");
        List<string> FindStrings = ExtractFields.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("#", ".").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")).ToList();

        foreach (DataTable dt in excelDataSet.Tables)
        {
            List<ItemValueHolder> FoundAddress = new List<ItemValueHolder>();
            int iDuplicates = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int iItemColumnIndex = 0;
                foreach (var fieldValue in dr.ItemArray)
                {
                    object cellData = fieldValue;
                    string sCellData = cellData.ToString().Replace("#", ".").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");

                    if (cellData != null)

                        if (FindStrings.Exists(delegate(string k) { return k.ToLower() == sCellData.ToString().ToLower(); }))
                        {
                            if (!FoundAddress.Exists(delegate(ItemValueHolder t) { return t.Item.ToLower() == sCellData.ToLower(); }))
                                FoundAddress.Add(new ItemValueHolder(sCellData, dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr), iItemColumnIndex));
                            else
                                iDuplicates++;
                        }
                    iItemColumnIndex++;
                }
                int iTotalFields = FindStrings.Count - iDuplicates;

                if (100 * FoundAddress.Count / (float)iTotalFields >= 90.00)
                {
                    var query = FoundAddress.GroupBy(
                item => item.ItemValue,
                (itemvalue, items) => new
                {
                    Key = (int)itemvalue,
                    Count = items.Count(),
                });


                    int dataStartAddress = (from p in query
                                            where p.Count == (query.Max(it => it.Count))
                                            select p.Key).Max();
                    dataStartAddress += 1;
                    string SheetName = "[" + dt.TableName + "$A" + dataStartAddress.ToString() + ":IV]";
                    string _selectCommand = this.ReplaceString(ExtractionStatement, "[Data$]", SheetName);
                    string reportDate = "";
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FindColumn))
                        try
                        {

                            int ColIndex = (from p in FoundAddress
                                            where p.Item.ToLower() == FindColumn.ToLower()
                                            select p.ColumnIndex).First();
                            DataRow drRowReport = dt.Rows[dataStartAddress];
                            reportDate = drRowReport[ColIndex].ToString();

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            //log 
                        }
                    string NewFields = GetNewFieldsAtSource(FindStrings, dr);
                    return new SourceFileDetails("", "", "", _selectCommand, reportDate, NewFields);
                }
            }
        }
        return (SourceFileDetails)null;
    }
```

Thanks a lot!